# How do I make thin lines visible in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke

For laser cutting, the stroke width of shapes must be very very thin.  This makes it hard to see those lines in Illustrator.

I know that in Inkscape there is a setting for "visible hairlines" which thickens these lines when zoomed out so they are always visible.

Does Illustrator have a feature like this?  If so, where is it?

I've found outline mode, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: So I understand... you **don't** want to change any stroke weights... you merely want to **see** thin strokes better when zoomed out? -- I don't believe there's anything for that in Illustrator. Might open a second window at a different zoom level - viewing both windows may help a bit - not sure really. Honestly.. I toggle outline/preview repeatedly.

Comment: You are correct.  I know that one of the computers here shows thin lines much thicker than others, even though the lines are .001in and have to zoom in a ton before they visibly change size with zooming.  So I believe it should be possible.

Comment: Well, I think that has more to do with the pixel density of the monitor than anything else - at least where Illustrator is concerned. Which is why it's different on different systems (different monitors). I'd wager the lines are easier to see on the better (retina/4k) monitor.

Comment: @Scott, or maybe the other way around because the lines are rendered with 1px stroke? Just guessing.

Comment: yeah.. could be `:)` I had thought of that as well but it was too late to edit. `:)` -- In any even Illustrator has no user-accessible options for or *any* preview. You "get what you get" and there's nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's the question.. then **no**, Illustrator **does not** have such a feature.

But why not just work the edits using normal, 1-2 point strokes, do your edits, finish, get it approved, etc and then, when the editing is 100% done, just thin out the lines at the very end before exporting for the laser cutter.

I mean, unless you have laser eyes, there's really no need to struggle and look at laser-thickness type of lines :)

Comment: Changing stroke width doesn't work well with symbols or files in which there are many layers that need to be unlocked per iteration.